# Files on inaccessible ubuntu partition on a windows dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I had Ubuntu installed along with windows 7 on my machine, somehow linux partition has got corrupted which incidentally has quite a few important files on it. I tried seeing the files from windows partition but I am not even able to see the linux module. I created live usb and there I could see my files but copy or move those files with error for access permission. Is there a way to recover my files? Appreciate kind help and suggestion if any to improve my question. Kindly also let me know if you need any further information in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

### Avoid Access Permission Error

I would suggest you run nautilus (file explorer) as root so that you can move the files no matter who is the owner and their permissions.

### Instructions

1. While at the desktop press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.
2. Then enter the next command: `gksu nautilus`
3. **If** a prompt for password comes just leave it empty and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. **Else** continue to step 4.
4. Now a new window for nautilus should open as *root* user which has permission to read, write and execute anything.
5. Go to your folder (user folder are under `/home/username/`) and copy your files to your windows partition.

### Recomendation

If you plan to do a fresh install of ubuntu try to make a separate partition for the `/home/` directory so that you can leave your information separated from the OS in case you need to do a fresh install again at some point.

I know that tinkering as a novice can lead to problems but is the best way to learn. So congrats on messing up.

Comment: Just want to add to this good answer, how important it is to regularly make copies of all user files. To another partition, a USB drive, the cloud, doesn't matter. It's a good rule to have your user files in at least two "places".

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `sudo` in the Terminal on the live USB system? I think it gives you root privilege even when copying from another system's data.

For copying directories: `sudo cp -R Source_Folder Destination_Folder`
For copying files: `sudo cp Source_File Destination_File`

Comment: I think there's more to that command -- the copy destination has to be in there somewhere.

Comment: Yeah... sorry Zeiss Ikon, that was foolish :-) I'll edit.